# SSIS Script Task has green arrow but now red arrow by default. how to get the red arrow for error handling?

Tags: c#, error-handling, ssis, control-flow

I see I am allowed to do statements like this within my script task:

```
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
```

New to SSIS, and I could not find this info:

SSIS Script Task has green arrow but no red arrow by default.  how to get the red arrow for error handling?

[image: s]

Comment: You make an arrow red by connecting it to another object and then right clicking on the green line and select Failure

Comment: if you enter as answer instead of comment i can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You make an arrow red by connecting it to another object and then right clicking on the green line and select Failure.

[image: redarrow]